# Redirect URIs are not allowed in facebook "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs"

Tags: oauth, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I had added many URIs including domain name, localhost and IP addresses "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs". They are still working till now. But now I add another one with IP address. The error message "New HTTP Redirect URIs are not allowed" is always shown. And even I add with domain name, it doesn't allow as well if not https. Is that because of "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" option that has been changed since March 2018? And how to do that "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" allows the IP address?

Comment: Hi, +Neo. Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 5):

You must add SSL certifcate to your domain to overcome on this error.